# Python open(path, 'w') fails to create file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am seeing bizarre behavior with Python open(.., 'w') on Linux. 
I create a bunch of files (file1...file100) in a new dir, each with:

```
 with open(nextfile, 'w') as f:
```

If the dir is empty, it always fails with:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../mydir/file1'
```

There is no issue with permissions whatsoever.

If I manually create "touch mydir/file1", then run the Python script again,
the rest of the files get created no problem.

I am using Python 2.7.

Anyone seen this?

Comment: Can you show the exact code you use?

Comment: You appear to be using relative paths; are you certain about your current working directory? Why is trying to create a file in `../mydir` and not `mydir`?

Answer (score 4):

I'm reproducing the error:

```
In [482]: nextfile='../mydir/file1'

In [483]: with open(nextfile, 'w') as f:
     ...:     pass
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-483-fa56c00ac002> in <module>()
----> 1 with open(nextfile, 'w') as f:
      2     pass

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../mydir/file1'
```

the `name` in `open(name, ...)` should be file name or absolute path, no relative path allowed. If path `../mydir` exists, try this:

```
In [484]: import os
     ...: os.chdir('../mydir')
     ...: nextfile='file1'
     ...: with open(nextfile, 'w') as f:
     ...:     #do your stuff
     ...:     pass
```

or use the absolute path of the file to open：

```
nextfile=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), '../mydir/file1')
```